# 20.04 Fresh Install; Initramfs

Tags: boot, initramfs, budgie

I deleted Ubuntu 20.04 while trying to install Xubuntu from a flash drive. The installation media was probably corrupt.

When trying to install Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 on the same laptop, I get the error "Initramfs: Decoding failed", before the machine shuts down. No system boots, although both the BIOS and UEFI seem to be fine. I tested the Budgie drive on a different computer, and it seems to have no errors.

What can I do? Will a live optical disc help? Please be patient, because I'm still a bit of a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved!

1. Go to see the clown Pagliacci.
2. Install Ubuntu/Xubuntu/Budgie with "safe graphics"
3. Boot into recovery mode from Grub
4. Open the root prompt and enter:

sudo update-initramfs -u

Press Enter and wait. When the update is complete and the prompt returns, press Ctrl + D (or whatever) to continue, and proceed with normal boot.

I booted into a normal Linux with this.